# One button file emails - Outlook 365

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to make a one button file macro that looks at the Catagory and files the email into the corresponding folder.
The issue i am having is I have to have code that is specific for each category as the folders have varying paths. Is there a way to not have to put in the full path  into the code?

See below example

```
Sub Move_Email()

Dim itm As MailItem
Dim CATNAME As String
Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1
If itm.Categories = "Customer1" Then
    itm.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("01 - My Accounts").Folders("Customer1")
Else
    If itm.Categories = "Supplier1" Then
        itm.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("01 - My Suppliers").Folders("Supplier1")
    Else
    Exit Sub
    End If
 Exit Sub
 End If
 End Sub
```

I would like it to be more like

```
Sub Move_Email2()

Dim itm As MailItem
Dim CATNAME As String
Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
CATNAME = itm.Categories

If itm.Categories = CATNAME Then
    itm.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(CATNAME)
End If
End Sub
```

Is this possible?

Attempt 1:

```
Sub Move_Email2()

Dim itm As MailItem
Dim Name As String
Dim FoundFolder As Folder
Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

Name = itm.Categories

If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set FoundFolder = FindInFolders(Application.Session.Folders, Name)

If Not FoundFolder Is Nothing Then
    itm.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(FoundFolder.FolderPath)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use FolderName to find Folder, For example:

```
Sub Move_Email2()

Dim itm As MailItem
Dim Name As String
Dim FoundFolderPath As String
Dim strFolderPath As Folder
Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

For Each Name In itm.Categories
    Set FoundFolder = FindInFolders(Application.Session.Folders, Name)
    If Not FoundFolder Is Nothing Then
        itm.Move GetFolder(FoundFolder.FolderPath)
    End If
Next

End Sub
Function FindInFolders(TheFolders As Outlook.Folders, Name As String)
  Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  On Error Resume Next

  Set FindInFolders = Nothing

  For Each SubFolder In TheFolders
    If LCase(SubFolder.Name) Like LCase(Name) Then
      Set FindInFolders = SubFolder
      Exit For
    Else
      Set FindInFolders = FindInFolders(SubFolder.Folders, Name)
      If Not FindInFolders Is Nothing Then Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Function
Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
 Dim TestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim FoldersArray As Variant
 Dim i As Integer

 On Error GoTo GetFolder_Error
 If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
 FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
 End If
 'Convert folderpath to array
 FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
 Set TestFolder = Application.Session.Folders.item(FoldersArray(0))
 If Not TestFolder Is Nothing Then
 For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
 Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
 Set SubFolders = TestFolder.Folders
 Set TestFolder = SubFolders.item(FoldersArray(i))
 If TestFolder Is Nothing Then
 Set GetFolder = Nothing
 End If
 Next
 End If
 'Return the TestFolder
 Set GetFolder = TestFolder
 Exit Function

GetFolder_Error:
 Set GetFolder = Nothing
 Exit Function
End Function
```

Please refer to this link:

[How To Find Folder By Name In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2087-outlook-find-folder-by-name.html)

[Obtain a Folder Object from a Folder Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/items-folders-and-stores/obtain-a-folder-object-from-a-folder-path)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, how to fit this in. The above code "Attempt 1" works and finds the folder, how do i then move the email to it? Also this seems much slower that a direct path, although i guess there is no way around this?(2-4 secs rather than instant)

Comment: I update my code, you could try this code.@Kevin Sharpes

Comment: Unfortunately that code gives me the following error
    Compile error:
    For Each may only iterate over a collection object or an array